# Method in swift which will be executed after user open app from background

Tags: swift, methods, view, background, fetch

does exist some function/method which is executed when user open app from background (not new fresh launch, just from sleep on the background)? Thanks

this doesnt work for me as i expect:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't specific to swift.

Your app delegate will get sent a applicationWillEnterForeground message. The signature in Swift looks like this:

```
optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

Next, the system will broadcast a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. You can set up a notification listener in any class to listen for that notification.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have questrion: Is possible to call method from ViewController in AppDelegate.swift? I found this method called "applicationWillEnterForeground" and I'd like to call 2 methods in there from ViewController (or from other Class). Thanks:)

Comment: The answer is "maybe". It depends on how your view controllers are created and whether or not you can get a pointer to them. It's simpler to use the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. Simply add a listener to that notification in your view controller's viewWillAppear method (and remove the listener in viewWillDisappear). Alternately, if you want the listener to be active even when the view is not on-screen, install the listener in viewDidLoad, and remove it in your dealloc method.